# Unable to search files by name in Gitlab Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitlab

I'm using the `gitlab-rails console` command to programmatically initiate groups, projects and repos in Gitlab. But when I cannot manage to get `repository.search_files_by_name` works. I don't understand why. I'm new to Ruby world and I don't know how to debug this kind of strange behaviors.

```
# Check if project is initialized... OK
irb(main):229:0> project
=> #<Project id:29 mygroup/mysubgroup/myrepo>>

# Check if repository is initialized... OK
irb(main):230:0> project.repository
=> #<Repository:@hashed/35/13/35135aaa6cc23891b40cb3f378c53a17a1127210ce60e125ccf03efcfdaec458>

# Create README.md in master... OK
irb(main):231:0> project.repository.create_file(user, 'README.md', '# Hello World', message: "update readme.md", branch_name: 'master')
=> "9ea5ef88f65a12ed6e676be945921c5f9556945c"

# Check if README.md is in the repository... OK
irb(main):232:0> project.repository.ls_files('master')
=> ["README.md"]

# Search for README.md... FAILED
irb(main):233:0> project.repository.search_files_by_name("README.md", 'master')
=> []
```

Here is the method declaration [app/models/repository.rb#L993-997](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/27b43bd4d613cc7b8773ca0863b8d8f9b90f6d87/app/models/repository.rb#L993-997) and How to use it [spec/models/repository_spec.rb#L912-950](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/ae96e65ee23d81be3924b87ed16becbbbe002b91/spec/models/repository_spec.rb#L912-950)

Thanks for you help !

Comment: The tests show searches by directory name, not filename. What if you make a directory `foo` and create `foo/README.md` and search for `foo`; does that return anything?